# http post from node js to ruby on rails with nested params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, node.js, api

I'm trying to send a POST request from a NodeJS app to a Rails app.

Here's the nodejs code:

```
var http = require('http');
var photoRequest = {
    photo_request: {
      bw_quantity: 0,
      color_quantity: 1
    }
  };

var photoRequestStr = JSON.stringify(photoRequest);
var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    path: '/api/v1/photo_requests',
    port: '3000',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Length': photoRequestStr.length,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
};
var str = '';

http
  .request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(data) {
      str += data;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
      console.log(str);
    })

    res.on('error', function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
  })
  .end(photoRequestStr);
```

and here's the rails code

```
def safe_params
    p 'PARAMS:'
    p params.inspect
    p 'END PARAMS'
    params.require(:photo_request).permit!
end

def create
   @request = PhotoRequest.new(safe_params)

   if @request.save
       render json: { :message => 'Success!'}, status: :ok, success: true
   end
end
```

And i'm getting this error:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/photo_requests" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-27 11:36:00 +0800
Processing by Api::V1::PhotoRequestsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"{\"photo_request\":{\"bw_quantity\":0,\"color_quantity\":1}}"=>nil}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "photo_requests" WHERE "photo_requests"."allocation_status" IN (
'no', 'partial')
"PARAMS:"
"{\"{\\\"photo_request\\\":{\\\"bw_quantity\\\":0,\\\"color_quantity\\\":1}}\"=>nil, \"action\"=>\"
create\", \"controller\"=>\"api/v1/photo_requests\"}"
"END PARAMS"
Completed 400 Bad Request in 5ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: photo_request):
```

Any idea how I can get rails to accept the params from nodejs? Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you do this `params.require('photo_request')` in your safe_params method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the nodeJS header code to `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` instead of `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` made it work!